# Lincoln Movie Website Page Slider

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm looking to create a effect similar to the effect that can be found on thelincolnmovie.com website. I attempted to recreate it using CSS3 transitions, but it's not quite where I want it.

My attempt can be found here: http://jasenpeterson.com/12-Years/v4/

The problem is that I don't want the current page to slide out and the next page to slide in (revealing the home page in the process). I want the pages to slide on top of one another like the Lincoln website.

I was hoping I could accomplish this with CSS3 but I'm not having any luck. I'm assuming I'll have to flesh it out with jQuery.

My google searches for a tutorial or article to get me started have ended failure. I keep getting results for content sliders that won't fit my needs.

Any help would be appreciated! I can clarify things if there are any questions.

Thanks you.

- JasenMP

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here.  Do you want a jQuery solution or some suggestions of which Jquery functions to use?

Comment: Never mind, I think I got it. Thanks for responding Jrod! https://github.com/Victa/curtain.js is the plugin I found.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jquery smooth scroller (see [this example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)). It is very similar to that effect, although I think it is actually done with DIV's simply stacked on each other. But that was only on a very quick look at the source code.

So where as Lincon changes the url as such:

```
example.com/?about
```

This work's using page anchors, so uses:

```
example.com/#about
```

Worth noting I have seen a few people say this is bad because Google only picks up a single page and it doesn't tend to form very well, but that is open for debate I guess.